# Mediainfo doesn't work with exec() function of php

Tags: mediainfo

$rt=passthru("/usr/bin/mediainfo ".$file );

echo  $rt;

?>
it doesn't show anything even if it works in the cli
i have linux ubuntu OS .
thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you can call `mediainfo` anywhere, some shared hosting provider prevent this from happening, in that case define the full path where `mediainfo` binary is located, ej. `/usr/bin/mediainfo`, review your `$PATH` enviroment var. on PHP.
2. make sure to pass the full path to the file to `mediainfo` and escape spaces and problematic characters.
3. If you don't have to, don't close your PHP file with the last tag, ej:

`file.php`:

```
<?php
echo passthru('mediainfo file.mp3');
// last line, no closing tag needed.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rodrigo ! but still doesn't work it doesn't display anything (blank page) not even an error or a message . the full path to mediainfo is /usr/bin/mediainfo and the full path to the file is also correct i chekced it . i tried to use ffmpeg by the same way and it worked fine, still don't understand why !!!